# Selecting specific Data per month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2008-r2

So i have a table that would determine the **Region Code** of a **Branch** Depending on the **Month**,
 Lets Say from `January to february it's Region code would be 1,` `from February to March it would be 2` and `for the month of april upto date would be 3`

so here is the sample look of the table 
[image]

i have a code that gets the data from a table, but what i want to achieve is that if the LoanDate of the selected Data is within the Dates above (between fld_Datefrom and fld_Dateto) it would use the fld_BranchRegion that is indicated like above above. (EG. the Loandate of the date is  `2013-01-12 00:00:00` it would use the RegionCode **4A** as indicated above and if the data is `2013-02-04 00:00:00` it would use the Region code **3**

here is the code i use

```
SELECT 
       TE.LOAN
       ,bp.REGION
       ,BP.ID
       ,TE.AMOUNT 
       ,te.ID       
FROM #TrackExpired TE
    inner join Transactions.TBLMAIN PM
    on TE.ID = PM.ID
    inner join #track BP
    on BP.ID=cast(TE.ID/1000000000000 as decimal(38,0))
WHERE ((cast(TE.EXPIRATION as date) < cast(TE.newloandate as date)) 
      OR(TE.NewLoanDate is null and (cast(TE.EXPIRATION as date) < cast(PM.REDEEMED as date))) or ((TE.NewLoanDate is null and PM.REDEEMED is null) and (PM.STATUS = 7 or PM.STATUS = 5))  )
```

The problem with this is that it generates duplicate values so i have 3 occurances of the dates in the **#track** table the number of the Data is also outputted 3 times with different Region Code!!

**Instead of outputting them i would like to achive on selecting the Region Code from **#track**
Based on the loan date of the Data.**

i just want to achieve that instead of outputting all of the region code, it would just use the Region code that is between the ranges based on the **#track** table provided..

Any Help? or other approach?? thank you!. sorry im new to SQL.

**EDIT** here is the code to create the temp tables.

**#trackexpired**

```
 SELECT PH.ID
      ,PH.LOAN
      ,PH.EXPIRATION
      ,PH.AMOUNT
      ,(SELECT T3.LOAN FROM Transactions.HISTO T3 INNER JOIN 
              (
                        SELECT MIN(T2.ID) as pawnhisto 
                        FROM Transactions.HISTO T2 
                        WHERE T2.ID > PH.ID
                            AND PH.ID = T2.ID
              ) T4
                        ON T4.pawnhisto = T3.ID

      )as 'NewLoanDate' 
INTO #TrackExpired
FROM Transactions.HISTO PH
    INNER JOIN Transactions.MAIN PM
    ON PM.ID=PH.ID
WHERE YEAR(PH.LOAN) = @YEAR
```

**#track**

```
   Select  bt.CODE
        ,bp.ID
        ,AREA
        ,REGION
        ,NCODE
        ,FROM
        ,isnull(fld_Dateto,GETDATE()) as fld_Dateto
 into #sort
 from Transactions.tbl_BranchTracking bt
 inner join Reference.tbl_BranchProfiles bp
 on bt.CODE = bp.CODE

 Select * into #track from #sort
 where @YEAR >= year(FROM)
        and
      @YEAR <= year(fld_Dateto)
```

Comment: These don't appear to be duplicates. Look at the PawnMainID field values; they are all unique.

Comment: @BillStidham those are just sample If you would scroll them up the set of 4A is the same of set data with 3 as region code. those are just sample screenshots

Comment: @BillStidham please check again the question i have edited the screenshots thank you.

Comment: It looks like the PawnMainID contains the branch id in its left section. Your JOIN between #TrackExpired and tbl_PawnMain are based on  a one to one ID match. However, your JOIN between tbl_PawnMain and #track are based on the branch id from #track and an extraction of the branch id from ID on #TrackExpired. Without knowing how these  two temp tables were constructed I would venture to guess that this branch id JOIN constraint is what's causing the duplicates because it's likely not one to one.

Comment: @BillStidham i have provided the code to create the two temptables as you have requested. thank you.

Comment: tbl_PawnHisto probably has multiple entries for a particular "main record". What is the output from this:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #TrackExpired WHERE fld_PawnMainID = '1397000000001600'

Comment: And, if that returns 1 then what is the output from this:

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #track WHERE fld_PawnMainID = '1397000000001600'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Test Data**

```
create table #LoanTable (
  ID  int not null,
  RegionCode nvarchar(50) not null,
  LoanDate datetime not null
  );

insert into #LoanTable values
(1,'5','10/01/2014'),
(2,'5','10/18/2014'),
(3,'5','10/02/2014'),
(4,'3','04/11/2014'),
(5,'3','04/05/2014'),
(6,'4A','01/09/2014'),
(7,'4A','01/05/2014')

create table #LoanDetailsTable (
  ID  int not null,
  LoanAmount INT not null,
  LoanDate datetime not null
  );

  insert into #LoanDetailsTable values
(1,5000,'10/15/2014'),
(2,1000,'10/11/2014'),
(3,2000,'10/09/2014'),
(4,1500,'04/13/2014'),
(5,5000,'04/17/2014'),
(6,500,'01/19/2014'),
(7,2500,'01/15/2014')
```

**Query**

```
;With RegCode
AS
 (
    SELECT RegionCode, MAX(MONTH(LoanDate)) [Month]
    FROM #LoanTable
    GROUP BY RegionCode
 )
SELECT LDT.* , RC.RegionCode
FROM #LoanDetailsTable LDT INNER JOIN RegCode RC
ON MONTH(LDT.LoanDate) = RC.[Month]
```

**Results**

```
ID  LoanAmount  LoanDate                  RegionCode
1   5000        2014-10-15 00:00:00.000       5
2   1000        2014-10-11 00:00:00.000       5
3   2000        2014-10-09 00:00:00.000       5
4   1500        2014-04-13 00:00:00.000       3
5   5000        2014-04-17 00:00:00.000       3
6   500         2014-01-19 00:00:00.000       4A
7   2500        2014-01-15 00:00:00.000       4A
```

Using CTE extract the Month part of the date along with Region Code associated with it, then join it with you data table on Month of the loan date and extracted month in cte and get the Region code whatever it is at that time. happy days :)

Comment: This would work, the problem is the Region code varies every month so it should be on a table like i showed above instead of hardcoded

Comment: @User6675636b20796f7521 yes thats fine you can add 12 WHEN statements in your case statement and provide the Region code for all 12 months of the year.

Comment: Yes it can change, it should not be Hard Coded it should be based on the table #track, a sample image was provided above. thank yoU!

Comment: Meaning to say it doesnt mean that if the month is 1 it would be equals to 4A,.

Comment: can you explain me this code? `;With RegCode` first time i saw that.

Comment: its CTE (Comman Table Expression) read about it on BOL, read the details in my answer hopefully it will explain you enough what I am doing in this code.